# frontend CRUD routing with actions

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, vue.js

So let's say you would want to create a basic CRUD todo app. I think it shouldn't matter if you are using the Angular, React or Vue routing. You would come up with a router setup like this

- /todos => view all todos
- /todos/:id => view one todo by id
- /todos/:id/edit => edit one todo by id
- /todos/new => create a new todo

So as you might have noticed the last route won't work because the `new` would act as an id.

**Quick fix for that:**

I could change the order and put the create route before the other two routes relying on the id. But then the user would never be able to call a new todo `new` if the id is the todo title.

**Quick fix for the next one:**

I could put something like `/view` before `/:id`. The route would look like `/todos/view/:id/edit`

1. The word `view` might be misleading because you want to edit the resource
2. The user might expect the route to be `/todos/:id` so `/todos/.../:id` might lead to a bad user experience

Is there a common approach for this? If putting something between (`/todos/.../:id/edit`) is the only way, does a common word exist?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a matter of opinion, but your original structure, aside the issue of order is spot on. The issue with the route param shouldn’t be an issue if you use an id of a uuid or something other than a title property of a todo. Most if not all users aren’t usually manually routing to CRUD views via url manipulation. I’ve never navigated around Facebook by reviewing post or similar resource ids and guessing the URL structure, I just click buttons and expect the edit view to appear for a post. Regardless of the url structure as long as I can edit my post and the flow of the interactions make sens

Comment: Thanks. I saw that Github for example uses this pattern. For the view route `repo/tree/branch/folder` and then they can replace the word `tree` with something else like `repo/new/branch/folder`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common pattern is to use the edit route for creating a new item using an id of 0. Although changing the order will also work:

1. `/todos`
2. `todos/edit/:id`
3. `todos/create`
4. `todos/:id`

Comment: thanks for your reply. I think I would change the order then ... but I like the way Github solved it the most. From my comment https://stackoverflow.com/q/60131176/7764329

Comment: Ohh I'm sorry. I didn't see that you already mention changing the order as a solution. But still, the id is usually a number and it won't conflict with the "new" word. And as Alexander mentioned usually the users arent manually routing to a crud operation.